# Adjust Photoshop space between words

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

Is there a way to raise space between words? (not characters or lines).
I frequently want to make navigation buttons for web design and so far i always add manually multiple spaces between words (like 15 spaces, and counting every single one)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i hope my translations are right for this: (it seems like i can't change CC Apps Language)

Its in the *"paragraph"* windows menu -- should be something like *spaces* or *distances*

[image]

and there you can change the distances between the words (first line):

[image]

dont know if there is an easier way.

hope this helps. sry for bad english :-/

Comment: Ty, it works. Although, it is really clumsy to use, and preview button is shaded.

Comment: Yes i also wonder why they could not manage a better implementation of that options...another sad PS story :)

Comment: It's "Justification" (Paragraph>Horizontal bars at the top right>justification).

Answer (score 0):

I run into this problem with certain fonts which put too MUCH space between words. Today I tried adjusting the kerning (in the character panel) between two words to an appropriate length, then I "copied" the blank space. I eliminated the space "betweenallthewords" and just pasted the adjusted blank space in between the words.  It's not the best solution but it would be easier than counting out spaces between each word. I wish Photoshop would include a tool to adjust the space between words.  But maybe I just haven't found it yet.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? Do you talk about a special version? I thaught the other answer shows the panel you talk about?

Answer (score -1):

You could create the needed space between words by using a different layer for each word, then use your smart guides to line up the words with your desired space between them.